# python celry + amazon EC2 failing because of the hash

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, celery, pickle

I'm trying to use Amazon EC2 in Python. When I'm trying to run the first sample from celery it works fine whe using RabbitMQ locally and whenever I'm relying on EC2, I'm receiving this message:
[2012-07-25 15:14:33,842: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: celery_test.add[2eed1b15-fda7-4036-be92-a7fd921f0f5d]
[2012-07-25 15:14:33,881: WARNING/MainProcess] Task Handler ERROR: PicklingError("Can't pickle : attribute lookup _hashlib.HASH failed",)

I can't quite figure at which point/object it's failing to pickle.

The code is from their sample:

```
@celery.task
def add(x, y):
   return x + y
```

and I call it this way: add.delay(4, 4)

Any hints of what I'm doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: Looks like SDS was broken in 3.0.3:
https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/876

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom-built Python? It's possible that `hashlib` module wasn't build correctly due to lack of `openssl-dev` headers. You can check it my manually running `import hashlib` in Python CLI on your server.